# Can I run a Tor relay with Norton ConnectSafe DNS?

Tags: relays, dns

I am trying to contribute to Tor Network by running a non-exit relay on my PC. Via the status window, I already received the comment saying that my relay is reachable:

```
Jan 17 01:32:13.420 [Notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.
Jan 17 01:32:14.830 [Notice] Self-testing indicates your DirPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent.
Jan 17 01:32:16.045 [Notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
```

However, later I received this message:

```
Jan 17 01:43:09.372 [Notice] Your DNS provider gave an answer for "uofdrs2ok67ar.net", which is not supposed to exist. Apparently they are hijacking DNS failures. Trying to correct for this. We've noticed 1 possibly bad address so far.
Jan 17 01:34:02.394 [Notice] Your DNS provider has given "54.200.75.96" as an answer for 6 different invalid addresses. Apparently they are hijacking DNS failures. I'll try to correct for this by treating future occurrences of "54.200.75.96" as 'not found'.
```

So is it because I am setting up Norton ConnectSafe DNS in my Router? If it is the reason, I am really sad that I cannot run Tor cos I need to keep Norton ConnectSafe DNS on to keep my Kids from bad websites out there on the Internet.
Thank you so much for reading my question.

Answer (score 3):

That is an issue in Norton ConnectSafe DNS. It is resolving invalid domain names. What is really happening is that Norton ConnectSafe DNS redirects to a Norton domain (used for advertising) in the case of misspelled or non-existant domain names.

Unfortunately, this behavior cannot changed from the user side. It is up to Norton to change it.

As a fix for your problem, you can use an alternative parent control solution (if it is DNS-based, it shouldn't redirect invalid domain names), or set up a separate machine as Tor relay and give it different DNS settings that will overwrite those of the router.